# Как сделать список со множественным выбором в Android?

Tags: массивы, android, java

Приветствую!

Нужно создать некий фильтр, где на входе массив строк, в списке ставим галочки на нужные строки, затем возвращаем массив с выбранными строками. Я пробовал реализовать это через другую активити, но возникли проблемы с возвратом массива в первую форму. Как можно это поправить? Или в идеале вообще избавиться от второго активити...

Спасибо.

```
public class filter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    String[] itemOwner;

    ListView lvMain;
    String[] names;
    String[] returnList;
    int i, j;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter);
        itemOwner = new String[getIntent().getExtras().getInt("itemCount")]; //хапаем из первого активити массив
        itemOwner = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("itemOwner");
        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

        // устанавливаем режим выбора пунктов списка 
        lvMain.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        // Создаем адаптер, используя массив из файла ресурсов
        ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemOwner);

        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnChecked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChecked);
        btnChecked.setOnClickListener(this);
        names = itemOwner;
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // пишем в лог выделенные элементы          
        SparseBooleanArray sbArray = lvMain.getCheckedItemPositions();
        returnList = new String[sbArray.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sbArray.size(); i++) {
            int key = sbArray.keyAt(i);
            if (sbArray.get(key)) returnList[i] = names[key];
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GraphPrintActivity.class);
        //пытаемся возвратить выбранные элементы
        intent.putExtra("returnList", returnList); // в ключ returnList пихаем наш массив
        intent.putExtra("returnListCount", returnList.length);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что вы перед этим активити запускали startActivityForResult(...) ? 

В ключ пихаем наш массив?

Вначале создаем массив  itemOwner, а потом берем его из Extras?

Comment: можно вместо другой активити вызывать кастомный диалог со списком, будет красивее

Comment: @alvin Диалог красивее??

Comment: эстетически красивее - вместо создания целой активити - у вас диалог

Comment: Вообще я не согласен, иногда диалог хуже выглядит нежели активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: вместо `String[] returnList;` пишите `public static String[] returnList;` и из второй активити у вас будет доступ к этому списку через `filter.returnList = ...;`

Comment: так и поступил) спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так вот надо 
[ListView в Android: Кастомизация списков](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/)

**UPD** В общим подход, имхо, со вторым активити плох с самого начала. Я бы всетаки подменял адаптер и просто обновлял существующие активити для мультивыбора, а потом уже обрабатывал список выбранных..